# Error when loading list item using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sp.js

I am trying to load list item properties when a user selects a list item from the `asp:ListBox`. However, I am constantly getting an error with the message that the request is invalid. Could someone help me out please? Thanks.

Usings:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
```

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            $("#<% = MatchdaysListBox.ClientID %>").change(function () {
                var selected = $("[id*=MatchdaysListBox] option:selected");
                var matchdayID = selected.val();
                readListItem('/sites/test4', 'Kola sezone', matchdayID);
            });
        });

    var item;
    function readListItem(siteUrl, title, id) {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
        var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(title);
        this.item = list.getItemById(id);

        // 'LanesCount' is an internal name of the column
        clientContext.load(item, 'Include(LanesCount)');
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.readSucceeded),
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }

    function readSucceeded() {
        $("#<% = LanesCountTextBox.ClientID %>").val(item.get_item('LanesCount'));
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
</script>
```

Error message:

> Request failed. Invalid request.
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.WriteChildItems(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object obj, ClientObjectQuery objectQuery, ProxyContext
>   proxyContext)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.WriteAsJson(JsonWriter writer,
>   Object obj, ClientObjectQuery objectQuery, ProxyContext proxyContext)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.WriteAsJsonWithMonitoredScope(JsonWriter
>   writer, Object value, ClientObjectQuery objectQuery, ProxyContext
>   proxyContext)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.WriteQueryResults(Object
>   obj, ClientObjectQuery objQuery)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessQuery(XmlElement
>   xe)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessOne(XmlElement
>   xe)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStatements(XmlNode
>   xe)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.Process()

Comment: Did you debug it...Where it is failing..which line?

Comment: It's failing after `executeQueryAsync` is called, obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in this step,

```
clientContext.load(item, 'Include(LanesCount)');
```

I have changed the code as

```
clientContext.load(item, 'LanesCount');
```

it worked for me. Check it.

Comment: I tried that actually, same result :(

Comment: Try the above code now.

Comment: Yes, that works. For multiple properties, it is needed to just keep listing the internal names of columns, something like: `'Id, MatchdayDate, LanesCount, TimeSlotsCount, DailyExpenses, Remark'`

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.item` to `var item`

After `var item = list.getItemById(id);`

Use `ctx.load(item);`

Then get the columns data using `item.get_item('LanesCount')`

Then try using `clientContext.load(item, 'Include(LanesCount)');`

Hope this helps.